# How to check the color code/color of an element in Appium?

Tags: android, selenium, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

**How to check the color code/color of an element in Appium ?** 
I'm unable to find the color of the element in appium because in one field I want to automate the output which is defined in different colors. How to verify this using Appium/UI automator.

Comment: Like @adam-burley answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66403312/6766297) You can use pixel color verify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Appium does not support color testing for element !

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done by Appium as underlying UIAutomator framework does not allow us to do so.
In app’s **native** context this cannot be done.

In app’s **webview** context could query the value of a web element's computed CSS property. Example:

```
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("SomeId");
String cssProperty = element.getCssValue("style");
```

Note: This command only applies to web view contexts.
More information is available at: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/css-property/

Summary:

- for element inside NATIVE CONTEXT ==>> NO
- for element inside WEB VIEW CONTEXT ==>> YES